# Why index is out of bouds?

Tags: java, string, substring, indexoutofboundsexception

I have this text `Hello, {between brackets 1}and{between brackets 2}`, I want to color the text between brackets with a certain color, here is what I did:

```
String text = "Hello, {between brackets 1}and{between brackets 2}";
String output = "";
while(text.contains("}")){                
    output = output + text.substring(0, text.indexOf("{"));
    output = output + "<font color='#00e1ff'>"+text.substring(
    text.indexOf("{")+1, text.indexOf("}")-1)+"</font>";
    text = text.substring(text.indexOf("}"), text.length()-1);
}
```

but I got an **indexOutOfBoundsException** in line 10 which is:

```
output = output + "<font color='#00e1ff'>"+text.substring(
text.indexOf("{")+1, text.indexOf("}")-1)+"</font>";
```

Comment: Read the docs for `substring()`.  Your second parameter is wrong.

Comment: I'd also strongly advise you to extract local variables for `text.indexOf("{")` and `text.indexOf("}")` then format your code... just doing those two things will make your code *much* clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `text = text.substring(text.indexOf("}"), text.length()-1);` you not deleting closing bracket. So text is `"}and{between brackets 2"`.

Try this:

```
text = text.substring(text.indexOf("}") + 1), text.length());
```

PS: learn how to use debugger. It is easy and very helpful in such situation.

Comment: possible typo: `text = text.substring(text.indexOf("}") + 1, text.length());`

Comment: Yes. I lost my bracket. Thank you